# Custom Table Container with <br> is not working in datatable in R shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, datatables, shinydashboard

##This is a container that I am using in the data table, but br tag in the column name is not working.
I used escape = FALSE in the data table but still facing the same issue.
and \n is also not working. I want something like this column name = first name (in the next line) last name.

```
    test <- function(group,n){
  htmltools::withTags(th(colspan = n, group, class = "dt-center"))
}

myContainer <- htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = '',style="width:100%",
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 2, ' '),
      th(colspan = 1, 'group 1', class = "dt-center"),
      th(colspan = 2, 'group 2', class = "dt-center"),
      th(colspan = 2, 'group 3', class = "dt-center")
    ),
    tr(
      th("new \\\\n ID"),
      lapply(c("SUBJID","SITE<br>ID","AG<br>E","SUBJID","RACE"), th)
    )
  )
))


Server <- function(input, output, session) {
  adae<-read_sas("C:/Arinjay_Intern/Work/ADaM/adae.sas7bdat")
  
  
  output$intTable<-renderDT({adae_df %>%
      
      datatable(class= 'compact', extensions = 'Buttons', rownames = F, container = myContainer,escape = FALSE,
                callback = JS(c("$('table.dataTable thead th').css('border-top', 'none');",
                                "$('table.dataTable.no-footer').css('border-top', 'none');"
                              )),
                options = list(dom = 'tB', pageLength = 5,
                               ordering = FALSE, class= "compact",
                               columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")),
                               buttons = 'pdf'
                               
                ),
                caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
                  style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: left;',
                  htmltools::em(HTML('N = number of subjects in the specified population. <br>n=number of subjects in each category. % = 100*n/N.')))
      ) %>%
      formatStyle(c("USUBJID","SUBJID","SITEID","AGE", "SEX","RACE"), backgroundColor = 'white')
    
  })
}

UI <-navbarPage(
  "DT Interactive Tables",
  tabPanel(
    "ADaM DataSets",
    fluidPage(
      checkboxGroupInput('group','Please select a group',c('FD_Cohort','MRD_Cohort')),
      textInput('n',"any value",value=2),
      DTOutput("intTable")
    )
  )
)


shinyApp(UI,Server)
```

[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neither `\n` or `<br>`, work in `xtable`. So, you could define the rows explicitly as shown below:

```
row1 <- c(" USUB","SUBJ","SITE","AG","SEX", "RACE")
row2 <- c("JID","ID","ID","E"," ", "")

myContainer <- htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'dt-center', style="width:100%",
  thead(
    tr( 
      th(colspan = 2, 'group 1', class = "dt-center"),
      th(colspan = 2, 'group 2', class = "dt-center"),
      th(colspan = 2, 'group 3', class = "dt-center")
    ),
    tr( lapply( row1, th) 
    ),
    tr( lapply( row2, th)
    )
  )
))
```

or you can write something in css or js to handle it.  The above code gives the following output on a dummy dataset:

[image: output]

Comment: any idea about how we can achieve it?

Comment: Did you try `escape=FALSE` rather than `escape=False`?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: escape=FALSE or escape=F only works for table contain. and in my example, I am providing custom headers to the table. 
Please the full code.